# Capistrano multistage variables

Tags: capistrano

When using ext/multistage, why aren't the variables that are set in a stage (production.rb) available in deploy.rb?

In production.rb: `set :domain, "domain.com"`

In deploy.rb: `set :vhost, "/var/www/#{domain}"`

But when I try to run, it complains

```
undefined local variable or method `domain' for #<Capistrano::Configuration:0x00000100d07248> (NameError)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems very silly, and I'm probably not doing this right, but it does work if I defer the variable setting in deploy.rb like this:

```
set(:stage_domain) { "#{domain}" }
set(:vhost) { "/var/www/#{stage_domain}" }
set(:repo_dir) { "#{vhost}/repository" }
set(:deploy_to) { "#{repo_dir}" }
set(:httpdocs_link) { "#{deploy_to}" }
role(:web) { stage_domain }
```

Comment: According to the guys on the Capistrano mailing list, this is the right way to do it.

Comment: can you explicit what you mean by defer?

Comment: do you mean that the `set :vhost, "/var/www/#{domain}"` of your question is not located at the same position than the `set(:vhost) { "/var/www/#{stage_domain}" }` of your answer?

Comment: @DirtyHenry same position. Its evaluation is deferred until the last possible second (when it's used instead of when it's declared) because it's wrapped in a block instead of a string (which would be immediately evaluated and therefore undefined, probably due to the order in which capistrano loads the files).

Comment: @devth Is it possible to attach parameters to a deferred variable? I want to change this "role :db,  remote_server, :primary => true" into this "role(:db) { remote_server }, :primary => true"

Comment: as simple as "role(:db, :primary => true) { remote_server }" ;-)